# Expressing the sum of two squared inner products more compactly: is it possible to lift the dimension?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

Let $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be two fixed vectors, and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ be the usual Euclidean inner product in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

My question is as follows. Is there an (explicit) map $T$, and a vector $v$ such that for every $x$, it holds:
$$
\langle v_1,x\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2 + \langle v_2,x\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2  = \langle v,T(x)\rangle^2_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}.
$$
Here $2d$ is rather arbitrary, and I'd still be happy if such a result holds true for some larger Euclidean space with dimension $kd$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is an appropriate constant.

**Extension:** Can we extend this to beyond two vectors. Namely, let $r\in\mathbb{N}$, $v_1,\dots,v_r$ be vectors. Then, is there a map $T:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{rd}$, explicit, and a vector $v$ such that 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^r \langle v_j,x\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2  = \langle v,T(x)\rangle^2_{\mathbb{R}^{rd}}.
$$
If not $rd$, can we settle for a larger dimension, $krd$ where $k$ is a constant not depending on $r$ and  $d$?

**Edit.** I came to realize without any further restriction on $T$ the task becomes ill-defined. For my application reflecting now, I want to be able to recover $x$ from $T$ (well-perhaps up to a sign flip: note that if $x$ enjoys the equation so do $-x$).

**Edit 2.** Silly me. I also want $T$ to be independent of $v$. It need not, however, be linear (and it should not be linear either).

Comment: In the generalisation there is a square on the right-hand side of the equation wheras in the equation for two there is none. Is this on purpose?

Comment: A typo; fixed now. Thx!

Comment: If $T$ can be any function, then the problem appears trivial. Just choose
$$T(x):=\Big(\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^r\langle v_j,x\rangle_{\Bbb R^d}^2},0,...,0\Big), \qquad v=(1,0,...,0).$$

Comment: M. Winter, thanks for the comment.

I have realized it was somewhat ill-posed. For my application, I want $T$ to be such that $x$ can be recovered (perhaps up to a sign, as $x$ enjoys the equation iff $-x$) from $T(x)$.

Comment: @kawa Alright. Then what about $$T(x):=\Big(\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^r\langle v_j,x\rangle^2 },x_1,...,x_d,0,...,0\Big).$$ and $v$ as before? Then we can clearly recover $x$ exactly.

Comment: I'm guessing you want $T$ to be independent of the $v_i$, and possibly linear?

Comment: Equivalently, are you looking for two functions: $V: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k, T: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ that satisfy your first equation?

Comment: Guys, silly me. As user44191 points out, I want T to be independent of v's.

Comment: What should $v$ depend on then? $v_1,v_2$ only?

Comment: Regarding Edit 2: this is getting silly. You start with $v_1$ and $v_2$ and then you ask for $v$ and $T$ that have certain properties. What does it even mean to say that $T$ does not depend on $v$? It presumably has to depend on $v_1$ and $v_2$. If not, then please rewrite your question with quantifiers in the right places

Answer (score 1):

A stupid solution is $$T(x)=\left(\sqrt{\langle v_1,x \rangle^2 + \langle v_2,x \rangle^2},0\ldots,0\right)$$ and $$v=\left(1,0,\ldots,0\right).$$